C# Code generator for another code generator, both share a library
This is a follow up question to my earlier question
Let me preface this by saying that I can get a single code generator running just fine.
My current solution looks like this, where I've written the dependencies in parantheses.
-- GeneratorLib [netstandard2.0] (Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp)
-- Generator1  [netstandard2.0] (GeneratorLib, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzers)
-- Generator2  [netstandard2.0] (GeneratorLib, Generator1, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Analyzers)
-- ActualProgram [.net8.0] (Generator2)

Now I click Rebuild in VisualStudio, this triggers the constructor of Generator1 which contains a Debugger.Launch(). We continue into the OnVisitSyntaxNode function, which calls an Extension method from the GeneratorLib, which causes the following error:

Could not load file or assembly 'GeneratorLib, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.":"GeneratorLib, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null

VS has no problems with it, I can GoToDefinition and it works just fine. I also see a physical GeneratorLib.dll in the bin/Debug/netstandard2.0 folder of the project folder.
I also included
<RestoreProjectStyle>PackageReference</RestoreProjectStyle>
<AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>

in every project, which doesn't help.
Why is this error happening and how do I fix it?

I don't remember the method name but as far as I can remember, you need to explicitly set the dependency, so you can use it.

@Fildor method Name seems to imply a C# function? I  already copied all <PackageReference>s from the dependency into the dependent project.

I cannot seem to find it anymore. But I remember having had to initialize one of the generation classes with an explicit "UseThisAsReference" (not the actual call - but it was something in that sense).

@Fildor I found that you could subscribe to the assembly loading event handler. Could it have been that sort of thing or something else?

@Fildor I finally found the answer from another question. You have to add the library also as an analyzer it seems...
